# GCP client library not working - SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, cryptojs, sslhandshakeexception

I have sample code to fetch regions from Google Cloud API. This sample code works fine from my laptop (windows with OpenJDK 1.8 version). But the same code fails from kubernetes environment which has suse linux with OpenJDK 1.8 version.

From Suse linux side I get :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:444)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:157)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:145)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.getRequestMetadata(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:603)
        at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize(HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:91)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:91)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequest(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:404)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
        at sample.program.gcp.vpvn.regionList(vpvn.java:85)
        at sample.program.gcp.vpvn.main(vpvn.java:307)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:994)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1340)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1315)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:264)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:113)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:441)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
        ... 23 more
```

When I enable SSL debug, I am not getting much details to troubleshoot this issue:

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1616080171 bytes = { 119, 66, 219, 23, 171, 247, 221, 79, 45, 202, 181, 18, 229, 4, 65, 98, 207, 90, 0, 108, 43, 54, 80, 65, 39, 31, 49, 114 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 215
0000: 01 00 00 D3 03 03 60 53   6D 2B 77 42 DB 17 AB F7  ......`Sm+wB....
0010: DD 4F 2D CA B5 12 E5 04   41 62 CF 5A 00 6C 2B 36  .O-.....Ab.Z.l+6
0020: 50 41 27 1F 31 72 00 00   56 C0 24 C0 28 00 3D C0  PA'.1r..V.$.(.=.
0030: 26 C0 2A 00 6B 00 6A C0   0A C0 14 00 35 C0 05 C0  &.*.k.j.....5...
0040: 0F 00 39 00 38 C0 23 C0   27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29 00  ..9.8.#.'.<.%.).
0050: 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13 00   2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33 00  g.@...../.....3.
0060: 32 C0 2C C0 2B C0 30 00   9D C0 2E C0 32 00 9F 00  2.,.+.0.....2...
0070: A3 C0 2F 00 9C C0 2D C0   31 00 9E 00 A2 00 FF 01  ../...-.1.......
0080: 00 00 54 00 0A 00 08 00   06 00 17 00 18 00 19 00  ..T.............
0090: 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D 00   1C 00 1A 06 03 06 01 05  ................
00A0: 03 05 01 04 03 04 01 04   02 03 03 03 01 03 02 02  ................
00B0: 03 02 01 02 02 00 17 00   00 00 00 00 1A 00 18 00  ................
00C0: 00 15 6F 61 75 74 68 32   2E 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 61  ..oauth2.googlea
00D0: 70 69 73 2E 63 6F 6D                               pis.com
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 215
[Raw write]: length = 220
0000: 16 03 03 00 D7 01 00 00   D3 03 03 60 53 6D 2B 77  ...........`Sm+w
0010: 42 DB 17 AB F7 DD 4F 2D   CA B5 12 E5 04 41 62 CF  B.....O-.....Ab.
0020: 5A 00 6C 2B 36 50 41 27   1F 31 72 00 00 56 C0 24  Z.l+6PA'.1r..V.$
0030: C0 28 00 3D C0 26 C0 2A   00 6B 00 6A C0 0A C0 14  .(.=.&.*.k.j....
0040: 00 35 C0 05 C0 0F 00 39   00 38 C0 23 C0 27 00 3C  .5.....9.8.#.'.<
0050: C0 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40   C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04  .%.).g.@...../..
0060: C0 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 2C   C0 2B C0 30 00 9D C0 2E  ...3.2.,.+.0....
0070: C0 32 00 9F 00 A3 C0 2F   00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00 9E  .2...../...-.1..
0080: 00 A2 00 FF 01 00 00 54   00 0A 00 08 00 06 00 17  .......T........
0090: 00 18 00 19 00 0B 00 02   01 00 00 0D 00 1C 00 1A  ................
00A0: 06 03 06 01 05 03 05 01   04 03 04 01 04 02 03 03  ................
00B0: 03 01 03 02 02 03 02 01   02 02 00 17 00 00 00 00  ................
00C0: 00 1A 00 18 00 00 15 6F   61 75 74 68 32 2E 67 6F  .......oauth2.go
00D0: 6F 67 6C 65 61 70 69 73   2E 63 6F 6D              ogleapis.com
main, received EOFException: error
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
```

Any hints on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Here with my sample code:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
Compute computeService = createComputeService();
        Compute.Regions.List request = computeService.regions().list("imageagg-nonprod");
        System.out.println("the list of regions for the selected project is \n");
        RegionList response;
        do {
            response = request.execute();
            if (response.getItems() == null) {
                continue;
            }
            request.setPageToken(response.getNextPageToken());
        } while (response.getNextPageToken() != null);
        ArrayList regionNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> ZoneList = new HashMap<>();
        response.getItems().forEach(region -> {
            ArrayList<String> zones = new ArrayList<String>();
            regionNames.add(region.getName());
            region.getZones().forEach(zone -> {
                zones.add(Paths.get(URI.create(zone).getPath()).getFileName().toString());
            });
            ZoneList.put(region.getName(), zones);
        });

        System.out.println("list of region for selected project is \n");
        regionNames.forEach(element -> {
            System.out.println(element);
        });
        System.out.println("the names of regions and Zones for the selected Project is \n");
        Set entries = ZoneList.entrySet();
        Iterator it = entries.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
        }
        machineList(ZoneList);
}

public static Compute createComputeService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        String proxyHostOpt = "web-proxy.in.software.net";
        int proxyPort = 8080;
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        HttpTransport abc = new NetHttpTransport.Builder().trustCertificates(GoogleUtils.getCertificateTrustStore())
                .setProxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved(proxyHostOpt, proxyPort))).build();

        //GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(abc,jsonFactory);
        List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
        //scopes.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform");

        String jsonToken = "{\n" + "  \"type\": \"service_account\",\n" + "  \"project_id\": \"imageagg-nonprod\",\n" + "  \"private_key_id\": \"99c871d2855b4d9388cc7a3a670a5764deb8c5e9\",\n" + "  \"private_key\": \"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQDh9k2JcCFrDZfm\\ng9DONfKe8xATwljEsW8FXMbPzU5JoXXsy1CYgkeW+eqXguQxFZM3HuI1W+mGBxgE\\n/K2P7XvJxylv7NajpgNmm4KGIh4hOpi+Sn3GVS31ftGM5A/CYKhRpr5uskr5PEin\\nDYxl0hUnfTodJCT+uxPxoCeN8aWuq5s+BapKKB8KVduUqmz3f8GL2Pc5wlm/YyOK\\nJYC781MAzLIFe8cLAVUJrVETqOtFTPCjy0yMGiUKxkyL20C11WFwfdD5ou0SD+6U\\nsT1YD/15KYh9GvV1E2XIPGzVtSHvU9h7FDRqOa+05QP3uDHegrAAib4PHA/A7KPD\\nBwkA6sW/AgMBAAECggEAHCPBtS9vIfdP5uecfcmvHMdVRbiquFgGZOsQYTmGmdnP\\nJz2MnGmBA9a8tc=\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n\",\n" + "  \"client_email\": \"315654350484-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com\",\n" + "  \"client_id\": \"112960668\",\n" + "  \"auth_uri\": \"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth\",\n" + "  \"token_uri\": \"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token\",\n" + "  \"auth_provider_x509_cert_url\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs\",\n" + "  \"client_x509_cert_url\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/315654350484-compute%40developer.gserviceaccount.com\"\n" + "}";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> map
                = objectMapper.readValue(jsonToken, new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){});

        scopes.add(ComputeScopes.COMPUTE);
        scopes.add(ComputeScopes.CLOUD_PLATFORM);
        //scopes.add(ComputeScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(IOUtils.toInputStream(jsonToken, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).createScoped(scopes);
        ServiceAccountCredentials serviceAccountCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(IOUtils.toInputStream(jsonToken, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);
        // Making call with credentials1 created with json string and proxy set as per requirements
        return new Compute.Builder(abc, jsonFactory, requestInitializer).setApplicationName("hcmx").build();
        
    }
```

My java version details:
java -version
openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)

Environment where code is running:
[root@hcm-pool-centos76-3 ~]# uname -a
Linux hcm-pool-centos76-3 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 6 15:49:49 UTC 2

Comment: 1) I do not think this is an SSL protocol problem 2) Provide your code and library versions. 3) Describe the environment that this code is running in. 4) What options are set for the VM regarding service account and Cloud API access scopes? Edit your question with more information.

Comment: Show the library imports and the versions that you are using.

Comment: I noticed in your updated question that you are using a proxy. That is probably your SSL problem.

Comment: I agree with @JohnHanley , this seems to be a proxy SSL issue, have you tried to remove said proxy to test this out?